# Dynamically add inputs to a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I intend to add dynamic inputs if necessary, in a form that is also returned dynamically in js. I am trying to do it this way, but it is not adding new inputs if necessary.

Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) { 
 Id = data1[i][0];
 DataRegisto = data1[i][1];
 Cliente = data1[i][2];
 Orcamento = data1[i][3];
 Ref = data1[i][4];
 Designacao = data1[i][5];
 Quantidade = data1[i][6];
 Valor = data1[i][7];

 linha1 += `<div class="input_fields_wrap1">
<div class="form-group col-md-2">  
  <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Refe[]" value="${Ref}">
  <span class="form-highlight"></span>
  <span class="form-bar"></span>
  <label class="label1" for="Refe">Refª</label>        
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2">                       
  <input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Valo[]" value="${Valor}">
  <span class="form-highlight">$</span>                     
  <span class="form-bar"></span>                        
  <label class="label1" for="Valo">Valor</label>        
</div>
<button class="btn btn-warning caixa add_field_button1"><i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-5x taman" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>`;
$("#retorc1").html(linha1);


$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields1 = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper1 = $(".input_fields_wrap1"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button1 = $(".add_field_button1"); //Add button ID

  var x1 = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button1).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    var length1 = wrapper1.find("input:text").length;

    if (x1 < max_fields1) { //max input box allowed
      x1++; //text box increment

      $(wrapper1).append('<div id="teste1"><div class="form-group col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Refe[]" /><span class="form-highlight"></span><span class="form-bar"></span><label class="label1" for="Refe">Refª</label></div><div class="form-group col-md-6"><input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Designaca[]" /><span class="form-highlight"></span><span class="form-bar"></span><label class="label1" for="Designaca">Designação</label></div><div class="form-group col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control1" name="Qtda[]" /><span class="form-highlight"></span><span class="form-bar"></span><label class="label1" for="Qtda">Quantidade</label></div><div class="form-group col-md-2"><input type="text" class="form-control1 Preco1" name="Valo[]" value="0.00" /><span class="form-highlight">$</span><span class="form-bar"></span><label class="label1" for="Valo">Valor</label></div><button class="remove_field1" style="background-color: #313348;"><span class="fa fa-trash fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>');
    }
     $('.Preco1').maskMoney({ decimal: '.', thousands: ' ', precision: 2 });
  });

  $(wrapper1).on("click", ".remove_field1", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#teste1").remove();
    x1--;
  })
 
});
```

No error is returning, but when I click the button to add lines, it does nothing

I'm trying this way:

I added the onclick to the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning caixa" onclick="adcElemento();"><i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-5x taman" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Then I created the following function

```
function adcElemento() { 
    let myForm;
    myForm = document.getElementById('retorc1');
    document.body.appendChild(myForm);
    let myInput;
    myInput = document.createElement('input');
    myForm.appendChild(myInput);
    myInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    myInput.setAttribute('name', 'Refe[]');

}
```

But it does not add inputs to the form.

Comment: I was unable to implement the solution that was given by @Rounin, if anyone can help to implement it in my code I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dynamically add inputs to a dynamic form

Create a `form` element:

```
let myForm;
myForm = document.createElement('form');
```

Add `form` element to document `body`:

```
document.body.appendChild(myForm);
```

---

Once you've got your head around creating an element and appending it to a parent element, you can approach creating an `input` element and appending it to the `form` element in precisely the same way in which you created a `form` element and appended it to the `body` element:

Create and add `input` element to `form` element:

```
let myInput;
myInput = document.createElement('input');
myForm.appendChild(myInput);
```

---

Creating and adding new dynamic elements to already-rendered elements is one thing, but what if you want to give your new dynamic element an `attribute`?

You can do it like this:

```
myInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
myInput.setAttribute('value', Ref);
```

And what if you want to add a `class` to your new dynamic element?

You can do it like this:

```
myInput.classList.add('form-control1');
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
function adcElemento() {
    let myForm = document.getElementById('retorc1');
  
    let myInput = document.createElement('input');
    myInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    myInput.setAttribute('name', 'Refe[]');
    
    myForm.appendChild(myInput);
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 12px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<form id="retorc1">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning caixa" onclick="adcElemento();">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I understood the explanation, but I didn't understand how to apply it to my code

Comment: Do I have to create a new function to apply this code?

Comment: No, not if you don't want to. Have a play in a javascript sandbox and get used to the DOM manipulation statements above. There are two dozen more, but these statements are a good place to start.

Comment: I am unable to apply your solution to my code. Can you put the example how to do it with my code?

Comment: I don't want you to create a new form, I want you to add the inputs to the existing form with the id `#retorc1` and the form you explained creates a new form

Comment: If you want to grab the existing form with the id `#retorc1`, you may do so with `document.getElementById('retorc1');`

Comment: I don't know what level you're at, but it may be that you're trying to run before you can walk. If that's the case then you'll benefit greatly from reading up on and understanding the Document Object Model (DOM). Here's a good place to start: [Understanding Basics of DOM](https://medium.com/jspoint/understanding-basics-of-dom-265b73d958d1).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222917/discussion-between-bruno-and-rounin).

Comment: I added to the question what am I trying to do with your solution, can you check if this is what I have to do?

Comment: Yes, you're almost there, @Bruno. I've slightly tweaked what you've done and added it to the answer above. It's important to note when you use `<button>`, if you _don't_ declare `<button type="button">` then you will automatically have a `submit` button (which you probably don't want) - so definitely get into the habit of writing `<button type="button">`.